# How to call a function inside the same class that destroys the Toplevel window? (Python, Tkinter)

Tags: class, tkinter, function, toplevel

I am not a programmer, just a hobbist, so I would be glad if you could tell me the ***"pythonic way" solution for my problem***.

***What I want:***

I want to create a Menu with tkinter that has a "New Game", a "Settings" and an "Exit" button, and if I click on the "Exit" button, I want an "Are You Sure?" pop-up window that has a "Yes" and a "No" button, and if i click on the "No" button, I want to destroy the "Are You Sure?" pop-up window.

***What's happening:***

The "New Game" and the "Settings" buttons are working exactly how I want,
but when I click on the "Exit" button, and I get the "Are You Sure?" pop-up window, I get this error:

***name 'varAreYouSureToplevel' is not defined***

***If this is NOT the correct way, please let me know how it's usually made.***

I am learning how to write classes, and it's a bit confusing for me,
when I try to use Tkinter inside a class.

***If you have a solution for this (using Tkinter root and Toplevel)
WITHOUT writing classes,
then I would be very glad to see it!***

I am using ***Python 3.4***

Thank You for your help!

[NameError - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4ypa.png)

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os


class classMainMenu(Frame):

    def __init__(self, varRoot):
        Frame.__init__(self, varRoot)
        self.grid()
        self.funcMainMenu()

    def funcMainMenu(self):
        self.varNewGameButton = Button(self, text="New Game", command=self.funcNewGame)
        self.varNewGameButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.varSettingsButton = Button(self, text="Settings", command=self.funcSettingsMenu)
        self.varSettingsButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.varExitButton = Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.funcExit)
        self.varExitButton.grid(row=2, column=0)

    def funcNewGame(self):
        self.varNewGameButton.destroy()        
        self.varSettingsButton.destroy()        
        self.varExitButton.destroy()        
        print("New Game")

    def funcSettingsMenu(self):
        self.varNewGameButton.destroy()        
        self.varSettingsButton.destroy()        
        self.varExitButton.destroy()        
        print("Settings")

    def funcExit(self):
        self.varAreYouSureToplevel = Toplevel(self)
        self.varAreYouSureToplevel.title("Are you sure?")

        self.varAreYouSureTextLabel = Label(varAreYouSureToplevel, text="Are you sure you want to exit?") # HERE IT SAYS: NameError: name 'varAreYouSureToplevel' is not defined
        self.varAreYouSureTextLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.varAreYouSureYesButton = Button(varAreYouSureToplevel, text="Yes", command=self.funcExitToDesktop)
        self.varAreYouSureYesButton.grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.varAreYouSureNoButton = Button(varAreYouSureToplevel, text="No", command=self.funcDestroyToplevel)
        self.varAreYouSureNoButton.grid(row=4, column=1)

    def funcDestroyToplevel(self):
        self.varAreYouSureToplevel.destroy

    def funcExitToDesktop(self):
        os._exit(1)


varRoot = Tk()


objectMainMenu = classMainMenu(varRoot)
objectMainMenu.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `funcExit()` you have e.g. `Label(varAreYouSureToplevel)` (and `Button` x2).

`varAreYouSureToplevel` is an attribute of `self`, but you are referring to it without the `self.`, so Python is looking in the global namespace, and you get the error you are observing.

Change these three statements to e.g.

`Label(self.varAreYouSureToplevel` and `Button(self.varAreYouSureToplevel`

And your code works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a messagebox instead of creating another window. Unless you want more than just a simple Yes/No.

```
def funcExit(self):
    ans = messagebox.askokcancel('Are you sure?', 'Are you sure you want to exit?')
    if ans: os._exit(1)
```